# How to log user credentials when authentication fails with Scala Play Framework and Silhouette

Tags: scala, playframework, silhouette

I have a secured action using silhouette, something like this:

```
def data: Action[JsValue] = silhouette.SecuredAction(errorHandler).async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
...
```

I would like to log messages when user fails to authenticate. And preferably the username he/she used to authenticate with. I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found that creating my own AuthProvider (or rather overriding the existing BasicAuthProvider) and adding a `MarkerContext` is the easiest. Like this:

```
class BasicAuthProvider @Inject()(
    override protected val authInfoRepository: AuthInfoRepository,
    override protected val passwordHasherRegistry: PasswordHasherRegistry)(implicit override val executionContext: ExecutionContext)
    extends providers.BasicAuthProvider(authInfoRepository, passwordHasherRegistry)(executionContext) {

  /**
    * Authenticates an identity based on credentials sent in a request.
    *
    * @param request The request.
    * @tparam B The type of the body.
    * @return Some login info on successful authentication or None if the authentication was unsuccessful.
    */
  override def authenticate[B](request: Request[B]): Future[Option[LoginInfo]] = {
    getCredentials(request) match {
      case Some(credentials) =>
        val loginInfo = LoginInfo(id, credentials.identifier)
        val marker: org.slf4j.Marker =
          MarkerFactory.getMarker(loginInfo.toString)
        implicit val mc: MarkerContext = MarkerContext(marker)

        authenticate(loginInfo, credentials.password).map {
          case Authenticated => Some(loginInfo)
          case InvalidPassword(error) =>
            logger.warn(error)
            None
          case UnsupportedHasher(error) => throw new ConfigurationException(error)
          case NotFound(error) =>
            logger.warn(error)
            None
        }
      case None => Future.successful(None)
    }
  }
}
```